# htaccess rewrite for two different urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my current htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.*) /b.php?n=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This changes my url **website.com/b.php?n=1&b=1** to **website.com/1/1**

I also want to change this url **website.com/g/1/1.gif** to **website.com/g/1/1**

How am I able to do both of these?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add to the with another Rule under the last one.

something like

> RewriteRule ([^/]+)?([a-z])/([0-9])/([A-Za-z0-9]*) /$1/$2/$3.gif [L,QSA]

that might need tweak depending on the rest of your urls

You could use a tool like Expresso to make/tweak your regex rules. (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)